# Carmen-Python: Invalid Json Object

Tags: python, json, twitter

I am trying to use [Carmen](https://github.com/mdredze/carmen-python) to infer the location of tweets that do not have explicit geocoding, but **Carmen doesn't recognize my valid JSON-formatted tweet as valid JSON tweets.**

When I run through the command line

```
$Python python -m carmen.cli [control.json] [test]
```

The file [control.json](https://gist.github.com/DavidYi1/d082902ee13c82349a4d) has only one of the tweets and it runs through properly. This tweet was obtained using Twitter API.

I used Tweepy to sample tweets from the Twitter Stream in order to write all the tweets into one file. Carmen does not seem to recognize the tweets as valid JSON. [JSONLint](https://gist.github.com/DavidYi1/da9889c809592af4032a) says that my tweets are valid JSON.

**Does Carmen only work for Twitter API and single tweets alone?**

**And if it does work for Tweepy and multi-tweet files, what is the appropriate input for Carmen?**

Comment: You should give an example so that we can reproduce the error you are receiving

Comment: Please add details to your post: 1) a shorter JSON example 2) the message you get ("Carmen-Python is saying that it isn't".  Thanks!

Comment: @AJK if you plug my list of tweets into  frontend " $ python -m carmen.cli [options] [input_file] [output_file]" with input_file as Json_Tweets.json, my error will be reproduced

Comment: @galath, for each line after running it through carmen frontend, it will return "json_tweets.json:1: UserWarning : Invalid Json Object. (The 1 is any line number that Carmen has gone through). At the end it will write "Resolved locations for 0 of 0 tweets.

Comment: Without more information I would guess there are some special symbols like [ or ( in your JSON-formatted tweets that prevent Carmen to accept them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of testing, it turns out that Carmen-Python works with both tweepy and twitter API.

The format my tweets was

```
{"tweet 0" : {"created_at" ...}
```

But it turns out that the "tweet 0" was unnecessary and the only required part was

```
"{"created_at": ...}
```

In order for carmen-python to work, the entire file does not need to satisfy JSON format, but each individual tweet does.